# Replacing regular expressions

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2012, replace

I have googled and googled, honestly, but I can't find it.

Using Visual Studio 2012, how do you replace all `A1`, `B1`, `C1` etc with `A2`, `B2`, `C2` and so on?

When I try with `([A-Z])1` and replacement `$12`, it replaces everything with `$12`.

Now I realize that it thinks `$12` is a backreference, and since it can't find the twelfth argument, it just inserts the literal text, but how can I tell it I want `$1` to be the backreference?

I tried things like `$1\2`, `$1\x32`, `$1\u0032`, but all that doesn't work. ideas anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know visual studio but in many languages, you can do the replace with:

```
${1}2
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you! Oh, you were too fast, I can't even accept your answer yet.